# ionic3- How to save data in localstorage and retrieve data in next page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to save data in localstorage and retrieve data in next page.I don't know How 
to do This?When I Tried The following code I get the data(voter_id)in console 
successfully but data is not displayed on `home.html` page

**Here is my code**

**check.html**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>check</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
 <ion-item>
<ion-label floating>voter_id</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="userData.voter_id"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button ion-button full color="lightText" (click)="check()">submit</button>
</ion-content>
```

**Check.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-check',
templateUrl: 'check.html',
})
export class CheckPage {
userData:any={
'voter_id':''
};
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
private storage: Storage) {       
}
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad CheckPage');
}
check()
{
   window.localStorage.setItem('voter_id', this.userData.voter_id);
   let voterId= window.localStorage.getItem('voter_id');
  console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('voter_id'));

  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
        }
   }
```

From check page I need to save data(voter_id) into localStorage and retrieve that data(voter_id) in next page `home.html`.Here I need to display the data in homepage(near voter_id in `home.html` page) not in console. How to do this? I don't whether I need to add anything in `home.html` and `home.ts` to retrieve data

**home.html**

```
<ion-item>
  voter_id : 
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Need to change in `home.ts` file like:**

```
pubilc voter_id:any;
constructor() {     
  this.voter_id = window.localStorage.getItem('voter_id');
}
```

**And also need change in home.html**

```
<ion-item>
  voter_id : {{voter_id }}
</ion-item>
```